# Maven ignoring repository defined in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I have a maven project which has a repository defined in its pom.xml. However when I run `mvn -U clean compile` on the project, maven tries to fetch artifacts from `https://repo.maven.apache.org` repository called `Central`.

I don't understand why maven is ignoring the repository defined in pom.xml

I also ran `mvn help:effective-pom`, and that too showed just one repository, which is `https://repo.maven.apache.org`.

**Some more background:**

I highly suspect this is a maven setup issue or something. I say this because the project I'm trying to compile is coming from a git source which is compiling fine for others, just not me. So pom.xml is defined correctly. It was working for me too on my old laptop. I just switched to a new MacBook and pulled the project and tried compiling it, and it's not compiling on this new MacBook. Don't know why. So I think I need to configure maven on my new laptop somehow, but I don't know what exactly is needed.

Comment: It would be good to see the relevant parts of the pom.xml. With a 4k reputation, you should already be familiar with [mcve]?!?!

Comment: First please show your full pom file...furthermore do you have a settings.xml ?